# Mean curvature and inner radius

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geometric-topology, curvature

Are there any relation between minimum of the mean curvature and inner radius of the embedding manifold in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: What is inner radius ?

Comment: @lanse7pty It is the most radius of the sphere, that could be inscribing in the manifold.